# Plot list of lists pixels in a vertical strip using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

This plots a single strip

```
values = random.sample(range(60, 100), 40)

width = 10
plt.imshow(np.repeat(values, width).reshape(-1, width), cmap='gray')
```

[image]

How can I modify it to plot all lists of lists next to each other, instead of a single list such as;

```
values_list = []
for x in range(10):
    values_list.append(random.sample(range(60, 100), 40))
```

Here is what I tried, but it only plots the last in the list

```
for i in range(len(values_list)):

    plt.imshow(np.repeat(values_list[i], width).reshape(-1, width), cmap='gray')

plt.show()
```

How to make lists vertically stripped next to each other

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `np.repeat`. Just `reshape()` to change it to a 2D array. The position can be set using `imshow`'s `extent=` parameter. To get the x and y limits correct, they need to be set explicitly. Setting `autoscale_on=False` prevents `imshow` to take over the limits. `origin='lower'` sets the values at `value_list[i][0]` at the bottom so the y-axis has its usual direction.

The code below uses the approach from [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/gradient_bar.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

values_list = [random.sample(range(60, 100), 40) for x in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 10
xlim = 0, width*len(values_list)
ylim = 0, max([len(v) for v in values_list]) + 2
ax.set(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, autoscale_on=False)
for i in range(len(values_list)):
    plt.imshow(np.array(values_list[i]).reshape(-1, 1), extent=[i * width, (i + 1) * width, 0, len(values_list[i])],
               origin='lower', cmap='inferno')
ax.set_aspect('auto')
plt.show()
```

[image: example image]

PS: To have the x-axis numbering the 'columns', set the width to 1 and add 0.5 to the x-positions. Optionally the distance between the 'columns' could be set larger than their width to get an effect of a bar plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

values_list = [random.sample(range(60, 100), random.randint(10,15)) for x in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(values_list)):
    plt.imshow(np.array(values_list[i]).reshape(-1, 1), origin='lower',
               extent=[i + 0.6, i + 1.4, 0, len(values_list[i])], cmap='inferno')
ax.set_xticks(range(1, len(values_list) + 1))
xlim = 0.3, len(values_list) + 0.7
ylim = 0, max([len(v) for v in values_list]) + 2
ax.set(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
ax.set_aspect('auto')
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot example]

PS: To have horizontal bars, just interchange all x-related values with y-related. `reshape(1, -1)` will be needed to have the pixels progress left to right.

```py
for i in range(len(values_list)):
    plt.imshow(np.array(values_list[i]).reshape(1, -1), origin='lower',
               extent=[0, len(values_list[i]), i + 0.6, i + 1.4], cmap='RdYlBu')
ax.set_yticks(range(1, len(values_list) + 1))
ylim = 0.3, len(values_list) + 0.7
xlim = 0, max([len(v) for v in values_list]) + 2
ax.set(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
```

Comment: can you please show how to plot the same values above on the y-axis instead of x-axis ? so that instead of stacking them vertically, you are stacking them horizontally from the y-axis and to the right.